# Replace (whole word only) that works for all possible keyboard-character combinations in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, escaping, eval

I am trying to find a non-deprecated method of comparing two strings in Typescript and/or Javascript that can handle any string that can be generated using the special characters available on a standard keyboard, because our application is fetching a randomly generated password from the backend then displaying that in our PASSWORD and CONFIRM PASSWORD fields, instead of fetching the encrypted password from the DB and including it in the response, which could possibly be decrypted with enough effort by someone attempting to crack our password hashing algorithm.

It is comparing the PASSWORD to the CONFIRM PASSWORD and checking if they are equal using the '**eval()**' function (because the validation condition is loaded from the DB, and could be "FIELD_1 > FIELD_2", not necessarily always equality checking. It does replacements using .replaceAll() on the condition based on form fields' current form value, then evaluates the conditions using eval(). However, replaceAll requires a regex, and regexes can't have certain special characters unescaped or else an error will occur.)

So, to try to find a solution that works for ALL strings/combinations of characters, I added code at the bottom of my question which will generate random strings and compare them for equality 3000 times, and if there are no issues, it will not print any failure messages. I noticed I can escape MOST strings successfully using the following:

```
 function escapeSpecialCharactersInTestString(str: string) {
      str = str.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$');
      str = str.replace(/[']/g, "\\'");
      return str;
 }
```

**However, it is still failing for strings like
`\3aeB296Z=DH\D"]Yu[0;MC.dep.UeE8g]&}sz)6N|M?.]q:%/` because of the `\3` giving the error `Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode.` I don't want to have to disable strict mode somehow and shouldn't be required to. However, if I use the *deprecated* "escape()" function instead, it always works.**

```
 function escapeSpecialCharactersInTestString(str: string) {
      return escape(str)
 }
```

**Looking for a solution that can replace any sequence of characters / any string, and I don't want to worry about using deprecated code.**

Code that tests 3000 equal, randomly generated strings for equality and stops if it can't compare them:

```
 const normalCharacters =
   "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
 const specialCharacters = "@:;#&-?/%+*[]\\_=^!()|{}\",.";
 
 function escapeSpecialCharactersInTestString(str: string) {
      // console.log(str)
      // WORKS 100% but is deprecated: 
      // str = escape(str)
 
      str = str.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$');
      str = str.replace(/[']/g, "\\'");
      return str;
 }    
 
 function generateRandomString(length: number) {
   let characterList = normalCharacters + specialCharacters;
   let result = "";
   while (length > 0) {
     let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * characterList.length);
     result += characterList[index];
     length--;
   }
   return result;
 }
 
 
 
 function evaluateConditionWithTrueOrFalseResult(testString: string) {
 
   let conditionResult = false
   let evalResult;
   try {
     evalResult = eval(testString);
   } catch (e) {
     console.log(e)
   }
 
   if (evalResult == true) {
     conditionResult = true
   } else if (evalResult == false) {
     conditionResult = false
   } else {
     conditionResult = false
   }
   return conditionResult
 }
 
 
 
 function replaceAll(str: any, find: any, replace: any) {
   //console.log("str: ",str,", find: ",find,", replace: ",replace)
 
   if(str == null) {
     return str;
   }
 
   if(find !== undefined && find !== null && find !== '' && find !== true && find !== false && !isDate(find) && isNaN(find)) {
     find = escapeSpecialCharactersInTestString(find)
   }
 
   if(replace !== undefined && replace !== null && replace !== '' && replace !== true && replace !== false && !isDate(replace) && isNaN(replace)) {
     //console.log("escaping special chars: ",replace)
     replace = escapeSpecialCharactersInTestString(replace)
     //console.log("after: ",replace)
   }
 
   // replaces whole word only because of the \\b 's
   return str.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + find + '\\b', "g"),replace);
 }
 
 
 function isDate(val: any) {
   let isDate = false
   if(val !== undefined && val !== null) {
     if(typeof val === 'object') {
       if(val._isAMomentObject === true) {
         isDate = true
       }
     } 
     if(Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Date]') {
       isDate = true
     }
   }
   // console.log("is ",val," a date: ",isDate)
   return isDate
 }
 
 
 let myOrigString = "'PASSWORD' === 'CONFIRM_PASSWORD'";
 for (let i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
   let formValue = generateRandomString(50)
   let escapedFormValue = escapeSpecialCharactersInTestString(formValue)
 
   let myReplacedString = replaceAll(myOrigString, 'PASSWORD', escapedFormValue)
   myReplacedString = replaceAll(myReplacedString, 'CONFIRM_PASSWORD', escapedFormValue)
 
   if (i > 0 && i % 100 == 0) {
     console.log("at iteration: "+i)
   }
 
   if (evaluateConditionWithTrueOrFalseResult(myReplacedString) === false) {
     console.log(myReplacedString, " failed at iteration: " + i)
     break;
   }
 
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval` to *compare strings*?

Comment: because the condition doesn't necessarily need to compare string equality. It is a criteria condition loaded from the DB. If it doesn't match the criteria, it shows an error. For example, say they were numeric fields. "FIELD1 > FIELD2" would need to use the eval function, since the condition is dynamic. It replaces FIELD1 and FIELD2 with their values in the form, then evaluates the condition. However, since these form values have special chars, it's causing problems when doing the .replaceAll().

Comment: You could use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) but *please* don't use `eval()`. If you need dynamic code you should at most be using `new Function()` so it doesn't close over variables you don't want to expose.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQYa1w).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I was able to implement "new Function()" instead of eval(), thanks (I kept eval in my original question though so these comments don't become confusing later). But it seems encodeUriComponent() didn't work because I am replacing on whole word only. See above (newly modified) code that is closer to my real code. I've added the exact "replaceAll" function I've been using, I didn't add it before because it's also checking for whether it's a date when doing the replacement and I didn't want to overcomplicate this question but it's already pretty complicated I guess

Comment: @jcalz update: encodeURIComponent(str); does work... gave an error when I put the solution in my actual code, but in the tsplayground it does work, so must be something else going wrong in my code. Sometimes it's hard to make sure the code I post in stackoverflow reproduces all of the same errors and possibilities that my actual code does... I'll keep trying and see if I can figure out what's going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how we should proceed with this question; if you keep `eval` in the question then any answer will need to digress to describe why it's a bad idea.  Even `new Function()` is not great, since you can get more or less arbitrary behavior from it which you probably don't want to support, like `"alert(1)"` or `"while (true){}"`. If you're thinking "well, that won't happen because I know exactly what will and will not be in that string" then you should be able to parse that string yourself and not rely on `new Function()`.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine a version of this question where someone can legitimately need to escape a string in order to compare it but I haven't been able to do so.